# Insert push a value in array with fieldname

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and I have created a very simple document structure with a 'userId' and an array 'words' that should contain fieldname 'wordId'.

Inserting the first document works fine. But then I am stuck adding a second value to the array of words. I have tried the following below using $push but I get the error message:

> "The field 'words.wordId' must be an array but is of type int in document".

Thank you if you could help me with the syntax of this operation!

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->test;
$answers = $db->answers;

$document = array( 
   "userId" => 1, 
   "words" => ['wordId'=> 1] 
);
$answers->insert($document);

$answers->update(array("userId"=>1),array('$push' => array('words.wordId' => 2)));
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast reply. Yes I have tried that as well. 
Then I get the error : 'The field 'words' must be an array but is of type object in document '

Comment: Actually PHP "array" notation is sometimes confusing, since this is not what the rest of the world calls an "array". In PHP `[]` and `array()` means the same thing. What do you actually ant the document to look like? I realized it was not an array right after the initial comment.

Comment: I do not know how to put in nicer format. But if I print it, it looks like this: array(3) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#9 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "5958a1e7e87cbf6434007321" } ["userId"]=> int(1) ["words"]=> array(1) { ["wordId"]=> int(1) } }

Comment: Point is "not an array". The document would look like `{ "userId": 1, "words": { "wordId": 1 } }` when viewed in the Mongo shell. You cannot add the "same key name" again. You either "overwrite" the "wordId" with 2 or we change to a "real" array. i.e `{ "words": [{ "wordId": 1 },{ "wordId": 2 }] }`

Comment: If you understand here. Your "first insert" was incorrect. And should have been. `->insert([ 'userId' => 1, 'words' => [ [ 'wordId' => 1 ] ] ])`. Then `'words'` is a real array and you can `$push`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This syntax indeed works. The syntax looks strange to me but I will try to get used to it.

Comment: PHP is kind of weird. But that's what you get.

Comment: So after the "insert" is done correctly then the `$push` is `[ '$push' => [ 'words' => [ 'wordId' => 2 ] ] ]`